# fadeIn fadeOut flashing upon scroll up and down

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, fadein, fadeout

I want to achieve smooth fadeIn and fadeOut when scrolling down and up. However, it is flashing too much. This is my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cbqxzub0/1/)

```
    $(this).scroll(function () {

        var y = $(this).scrollTop();    
           if (y > 70) 
{    
          $('.header-content-wrapper').fadeIn().removeClass('selected3').addClass("selected");
                }
            else if (y < 70) {

         $('.header-content-wrapper').fadeOut().addClass('selected3').removeClass("selected");

            }

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you do not have a "selected3" class declaration on your css. Secondly, the fadeout is flashing because your "header-content-wrapper" class has a "display : block !important" remove that and should be ok. if you want block display, you don't have to set it, it is the default value.

---

**EDIT**:

**JS (removed fade in/out functions)**

```
var faded = true
$(this).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (y > 70 && faded) {
    faded = !faded
    $('.header-content-wrapper').animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 500, function() {
      $('.header-content-wrapper').removeClass('selected3').addClass("selected");
      $('.header-content-wrapper').animate({
        opacity: 1
      });
    });
  } else if (y < 70 && !faded) {
    faded = !faded
    $('.header-content-wrapper').animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 500, function() {
      $('.header-content-wrapper').addClass('selected3').removeClass("selected");
      $('.header-content-wrapper').animate({
        opacity: 1
      });
    });

  }
});
```

Comment: If I remove display:block! important; then .header-content-wrapper will  become display:none and it will hide the div element after fadeOut

Comment: No, this is simply position:fixed. I don't want like this. I want to settle out the div smoothly when scrolling after 70px